# Retrieving data from Textbox in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, fancybox

I try to get text from a textbox which is in a fancybox from code behind, but the text is always empty "".

My aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Wertpapiere.aspx.vb" Inherits="Aktien.Werpapiere" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            /* Using custom settings */

            $("a#aAdd").fancybox({
                    'hideOnContentClick': true,
                    'closeBtn': false,
                    'autoSize': true,
                    'minWidth': 500,
                    'minHeight': 150
                });
        });


    </script>

    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <a id="aAdd" href="#dAdd"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add</a>

        <div style="display:none">
            <div id="dadd">
                <h2>Add new item</h2>
                <label id="lName" for="tbName">Name:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAdd" class="btn btn-add" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" class="btn btn-cancel" runat="server" OnClientClick="$.fancybox.close()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Code Behind code:

```
Private Sub lbAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbAdd.Click
    AddNewItem(tbName.Text)
End Sub
```

How can I get the text that has been entered?

I tried to edit jquery.fancybox.js and jquery.fancybox-buttons.js (appendTo('body') to appendTo('form1)), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript and jquery for getting value of one textbox to another try this logic:

```
var text1 = $("#textBox1").val();
$("#textBox2").val(text1);
```

may be it helps.